# How to update ListPreferences after implementing OnChangeListener

Tags: android, preference

I have PrefActivity and I use OnChange Listener to make a toast when ever user change any button in list preferences.
But now I have 2 problems:
1-first time that user change an option toast is not shown
2-after that, when ever user change prefrences, the value of list is not updated, and is always set on second value.

this is my code:

```
public class PrefsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

private ListPreference myPreference;
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);

SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

}

 public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences arg0, String key) {

ListPreference lp = (ListPreference) findPreference("blocktype");
 lp.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(PrefsActivity.this, "second", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;


    }

});
}
}
```

What is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As no one answered my question I figured out, where is problem.

```
return false
```

should be changed to

```
return true
```

in order to update the preferences

Comment: thank you man, it takes me half hour and I did not notice that.